# Editable default string in Haskell's terminal input

Tags: haskell

I want to be able to prompt the user for input (let's say a `FilePath`), but also to offer a *mutable/interactive* string as a default, so instead of having the user type the full path, I can prompt with:

```
C:\Users\John\project\test
```

and have them be able to backspace 4 times and enter `final` to yield `C:\Users\John\project\final`, rather than type the entire path.

However printing a default string with `putStr` or `System.IO.hPutStr stdout` *does* print this default to the terminal, but does not allow me to alter any of it. E.g.

```
import System.IO

main = do
  hSetBuffering stdout NoBuffering
  putStr "C:\\Users\\John\\project\\test"
  l <- getLine
  doSomethingWith l
```

I suspect `Data.Text.IO`'s `interact` may be able to do what I want but I could not get it to work.

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`getLine` doesn’t offer any facility for line editing. For this you can use a library like [`haskeline`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/haskeline) instead, for example:

```
import System.Console.Haskeline

main :: IO ()
main = do
  runInputT defaultSettings $ do
    mInput <- getInputLineWithInitial "Enter path: "
      ("C:\\Users\\John\\project\\test", "")
    case mInput of
      Nothing -> do
        outputStrLn "No entry."
      Just input -> do
        outputStrLn $ "Entry: " ++ show input
```

An alternative is to invoke the program with a wrapper that provides line editing, such as [`rlwrap`](https://github.com/hanslub42/rlwrap). For building a more complex fullscreen text UI, there is also [`brick`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/brick), which provides a simple text editing component in `Brick.Widgets.Edit`.